# How do I reduce the number of parameters in an ActionResult in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Archive(string id, int ids = 0, int idd = 0)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case "News":
            ViewData["ArtCat"] = "News";
            ids = 1;
            break;
        case "Opinions":
            ViewData["ArtCat"] = "Opinions";
            ids = 2;
            break;
        case "Features":
            ViewData["ArtCat"] = "Features";
            ids = 3;
            idd = 4;
            break;
    }
    var article = from c in _entity.Articles
                    where (c.ArtCatID == ids) || (c.ArtCatID == idd)
                    orderby c.ID
                    select c;
    return View(article);
}
```

Is there any other way to make this more efficient?

Comment: Not clear on why you're passing in ids and idd when you set them internally. Also, is it possible 'id' might not be one of the 'case' options?

Comment: This is a ridiculous effort at posting a question, honestly.

Comment: It is running so slow that you have to improve the performance?

Comment: You should put at least as much effort into helping yourself than you would expect anyone else to do for you, especially for a question that can only really help your very specific case.

Comment: @danny yes it is running slow. What i wish to happen is to get data from 3 different category ids but still able to get data from 1 category id.

Comment: Do you really need this to be 1 method, can't you just split it up into appropriately named methods with appropriate signatures?

Comment: @Paul Please see my answer. At the bottom, I ask for clarification for what your `idd` and `ids` are used for.  If we could see your table structure and sample data, it would help in refactoring this. I'm not sure why you need all three Ids just to get something.

Comment: @james Actually I did that. Is it more efficient that way?

Comment: Depends what type of efficiency you are trying to achieve.  If this code is really running slow then presumably that is down to the database query and nothing to do with this code itself - since the code doesn't do much processing at all.  But in terms of being understandable code that someone else could work with (or you will remember how it works in a few weeks) then yes it is far more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

First, set up a route that can handle what you're looking for:

```
Route.MapRoute(
    "ArticleArchive"
    "/Article/Archive/{category}/{archiveId}",
    new { controller = Article, action = Archive, category="all", archiveId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then, in your action result, you can do the following:

```
private _entity = new ArticleRepository();
public ActionResult Archive(string category, int archiveId)
{
    var article = entity.GetArticleArchivesByCategoryAndID(category, archiveId);
    return View(article);
}
```

Your repository class should actually handle getting the article:

```
public class ArticleRepository
{
    private MyEntityContext _entity = new MyEntityContext();
    public IEnumerable<Article> GetArticleArchivesByCategoryAndID(string category, string id)
    {
        var articles = from c in _entity.Articles
            where (c.Category == category && c.ArtCatID == id)
            orderby c.ID
            select c;
    return articles;
    }

}
```

No need for `ViewData`, and you don't need to have a switch statement in your action result.  This code is a little wonky because the need for your `idd` and `ids` isn't immediately clear.  If you could clarify that, it would help.

Comment: Thank you for editing and answering instead of piling on.

Comment: i used 'idd' and 'ids' when i need to get data from 2 different Category in 1 list. like when i click the Features link, it needs to get data with CatIDs 3 or 4 in the same list.

Comment: @paul so the Category name "Features" has both `Idd = 3` and `Ids = 4` in it, right?  If so, you can simply send back a Category name as a `string` parameter in the Action Result and use that.

Answer (score 0):

- Create an ActicleType enum
- Use this enum instead of string for id
- get rid of ids and idd
- Add ArticlyType field to Acticles table
- Query by article type